# Does doing an iPhone restore remove Exchange ActiveSync's ability to remote wipe a device?

Tags: iphone, ios, mail.app, exchange-activesync

I work as a contractor and a client provided me with an Exchange/Office 365 email account. I added this as normal mail account to my iPhone without reading the small print and afterwards realised this could give my client the ability to wipe my device remotely. This is a problem for me. Apart from the small print, I did not get any notification or answer any yes/no questions about enrolling my device when I added the account.

I removed the account, but was still concerned. So I erased my iPhone, and then **restored my iPhone to an iCloud backup from the day before I added this email account to my device.** I did not install an MDM policy at any point. **Will the device still be enrolled in a remote management program with my client? Will they still be able to remotely wipe my device?**

As a footnote, I am not sure that adding the account actually worked or actually did enroll my device - it could not sync mail and if I go into Outlook in a browser and navigate to Settings -> General -> Mobile Devices, my device is not listed there. Still, it would be good to know what controls my client has.

Answer (score 3):

There seems to be some confusion that Intune or an MDM is required to remotely wipe a mobile device. [Exchange ActiveSync can wipe a mobile device](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/clear-mobiledevice?view=exchange-ps) *without* an MDM. Hence, the message that Apple shows when adding a Microsoft Exchange account: `Adding an Exchange account will allow the Exchange administrator to remotely manage your device. The administrator can add/remove restrictions and remotely erase your device.`

This warning is true, and has been true for over 10 years. An Exchange administrator doesn't need Intune or anything else to completely erase an iPhone connected to their Exchange (doesn't matter if it's a personal one or a company device). To more directly answer your question, removing the email account from your phone prevents them from wiping the device this way as well.

Two caveats:

1. An administrator can (or *should*) use the [-AccountOnly](https://practical365.com/performing-account-only-remote-wipes-of-mobile-devices-in-exchange/) switch of Clear-MobileDevice to only wipe the data they care about (added in 2016). But, it doesn't change the fact that they *can* wipe the entire device.
2. If you use the **Outlook app** on your phone (not the built-in Mail app) then it sandboxes the data, and a remote wipe will only wipe the app clean, not the entire phone. This has the downside of not being able to collate and see *all* your calendars and contacts in the built-in apps, but has the plus side of saving your device from being fully wiped (purposefully or accidentally) by some administrator.

Answer (score 0):

> Will the device still be enrolled in a remote management program with my client? Will they still be able to remotely wipe my device?

Generally speaking, no.

That comes with a caveat, however.  It depends on the policy and how the device was enrolled (with Microsoft Intune).

First, understand that there are many different profiles that an admin can deploy including one for contractors who typically BYOD (Bring Your Own Device).  Unlike organization owned devices (used by employees), they need to provide you access to corporate resources on the devices you bring into their organization.

> and afterwards realised this could give my client the ability to wipe my device remotely.

This is standard practice.  This is about data security not some ability to be malicious with their policy enforcement.  Should you lose your device or your contract conclude, there needs to be a way for company to ensure that *their* data isn’t released out into the wild.

There are options both on the profile and on the admin console that allow a wipe from the entire device down to just removing the apps and data.  A contractor profile (depending on the sensitivity of data accessed) usually has the latter.  There’s even an option that after a wipe, the device be re-enrolled (or not) back with the Intune server.

Generally speaking, when you sign your contract there’s verbiage about your responsibilities to protect data, etc.  They should disclose to you that any device you want to connect to their network is subject to their rules and they remain in effect so long as your contract is in effect and you’re connected to their network/servers.  When you separate, they will no longer have legal status to control/wipe your device.

Comment: Thanks @Allan. I understand and have no problem with them wiping their data from my device, but as I have other clients I can't have them wipe my entire device, which the message "Adding an Exchange account will allow Exchange administrator to remotely manage your device. The administrator can add/remove restrictions and remotely erase your device." hints is possible. Continued below...

Comment: Adding the account through Settings -> Mail -> Add Account is the only interaction my device has had with my client's systems, and I've never done anything with Intune to enroll my device. I'm not sure if this is something that could happen automatically simply by adding the exchange account to apple mail?

Comment: Intune is what *they* use to manage mobile devices.  Wiping the device should only be used as a last resort like if your device is lost or stolen.  Wiping it entirely at the conclusion of your contract or maliciously  as a retaliatory    action against you would be legally actionable by you.   Make sure to have a lawyer look over the fine print *prior* to enrolling your device.

Comment: We used an Exchange server and the way I understood it was that the policy was in relation to you using Outlook and the ability to then wipe data from **Outlook only** not the whole device. This is something you should likely look upon the Microsoft KB to verify *exactly* what the capabilities are as it supposedly relied on the use of Outlook and an Exchange account with no profiles, MDM or anything else required for remotely wiping all the account data from Outlook.

Comment: It depends on the organization needs/requirements @SteveChambers.  The setup you referenced is just one profile/policy that can be deployed and it isn’t limited to just Exchange

Answer (score 0):

Removing the MDM profile removes all MDM control over your device, no need for a wipe. However, it is likely that a restore from backup will also restore the  MDM Profile, so removing the profile is the only way to ensure that the MDM is no longer able to access your iPhone.

Adding an email account to your phone does NOT provide the ability to wipe your phone. Only accepting an MDM profile will do so, usually OTA or via installing an MDM app...in other words, you will have to accept and grant the tool permissions first, it can't 'sneak' in.

Of course, since the email account is managed from the company Exchange server, they can wipe the emails themselves on the server, but it will not impact any other email accounts.

Comment: Thanks @cmason. A profile was never installed - I checked this in General -> VPN & Device Management (and in addition to this the restore was from before I added the account to my phone). The question is driven by the message "Adding an Exchange account will allow Exchange administrator to remotely manage your device. The administrator can add/remove restrictions and remotely erase your device." that comes up when you attempt to add an Exchange mailbox. I am not sure if I would prompted to further accept any profiles as part of this process if the install was working normally.