# Employer control over iPhone device

Tags: iphone, ios, ms-office, vpn

How does the 4 cases compare in the context of employer's control over iPhone from technical point of view:

1. A device is a managed device and such info appears in the main Settings menu, but is not registered in Settings > General > VPN & Device Management.
2. A device is registered in employer's system via Settings > General > VPN & Device Management and is a managed device (as in point 1).
3. A device is registered in employer's system via Settings > General > VPN & Device Management and is not a managed device.
4. A device is only registered via Microsoft Authenticator in employer's system, with Outlook and Teams being used (with 1 and 2 being false).

Comment: Is the device owned by the employer or the employee?

Comment: @SolarMike I assume 1 and 2 is an employer-owned device, while 3 and 4 may be both employer's and employee's device

Comment: You should make that clear otherwise you expect people to guess?

Comment: @SolarMike Why would they guess? I don't get your point, the ownership of the device should not matter, should it? What matters is if the device is a managed one and if it is enrolled in MDM. Or do you mean something else?

Comment: It matters a lot. If the device is employer-owned, the employer legally has full control independent of any technical settings (e.g. they could just ask you to give back the device).

Comment: If my employer asks to put a management system on my iPhone the answer is a clear "NO" also available using 7 letters.

Comment: @nohillside You are right, I'll edit the question to make it clear I'm asking only about technical side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to all of these is it depends how your employer has configured Microsoft products on their admin side.

They can enforce none of the possible levers to manage the apps in each of your 4 scenarios so they are all equivalent at that moment.

Down the road, they could change things to tighten up what restrictions they impose.

In the end, everything boils down to two main facts:

1. They own the device due to claiming it in the portal they have with Apple and they can force remote enrollment each time it is wiped. You will be prompted during setup if this is the case. Pay attention to what the prompts list.
2. They push a MDM payload (or compel you to self enroll) and then iOS tells you exactly what it has done to modify your device under profiles. You will be prompted when you enable this via Exchange Active sync and you can always inspect the settings app to determine a device’s current MDM status.

An [MDM-commanded erase only can happen](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicemanagement/erase_a_device) when it’s entitled with **Required Access Right: AllowDeviceErase** on the device. This means your scenario 2 is the sole one when you should prepeare for a remote erase (or follow the link above for remote lock, remote reboot, remote shutdown).

It’s not clear what practical problem you face and you would need to be explicit with screen shots and exact iOS versions for us to go deeper into scenario 1 (which seems very uncommon or unlikely).

4 is a personal device so no management other than what the app sends back to Microsoft.

2-3 reflects my “enrollment” text above.

Comment: "4 is a personal device so no management other than what the app sends back to Microsoft" -> is the fact that the device is a personal one sufficient to state this? Some other threads suggest that Exchange can wipe your device despite it is a personal one: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/460329/does-doing-an-iphone-restore-remove-exchange-activesyncs-ability-to-remote-wipe , https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/344261/can-my-iphone-be-wiped-when-i-am-connected-to-my-employers-exchange-server?rq=1

Comment: @mrn You don't mention Exchange in your question.

Comment: @nohillside You are right, but Outlook may use Exchange, right? Or am I mixing using mail service with device-wide Exchange ActiveSync service?

Comment: @mrn Outlook might interact with an Exchange server, but this isn't the same as using [Exchange ActiveSync](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchange_ActiveSync). It also matters whether you use Apple Mail or Outlook to access your Exchange account (https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/469227/9058).

Comment: Here’s a specific example. Any Microsoft iOS app can be configured to not run ever on a personal device, it can be configured to be strictly sandboxed (encrypted data and no sharing, no import files, no airdrop) whether the device is managed or not. This really isn’t about iOS. It’s about how the apps are programmed. I would ask a more narrow follow on question @mrn this one is going to be a seminar / 20 part answer to address every combination, possibility, permutation.

Comment: No app can erase your device @mrn unless it has a configuration profile installed stating that capability has been granted - and you always control your backups so if I’m wrong, you can always restore.

Comment: @bmike, so if I understand correctly, for non-managed, non-MDM-enrolled devices, if you add Exchange ActiveSync account to your iOS device (Settings > Mail > Add Account), then a built-in app (default mail app) is the one that can wipe the device as it has the capability granted by default. In case you are using Outlook, then it cannot wipe the device as it doesn't have the necessary capability. Is this correct?

Comment: Applications can not erase a device. They can only delete their data. For exchange sync, that’s not even an app, so it could only delete content server side and hope the device syncs that delete. Only MDM can send the erase command and that requires  an erase tntitlement which is shown to you in profiles. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicemanagement/erase_a_device

Comment: @bmike https://support.apple.com/en-us/105128 - this site says that setting up an Exchange account on your device gives the administrator the ability to wipe the device. Do you consider this as setting up a MDM?

Comment: “Remotely manage and wipe” matches my definition of MDM @mrn when you perform those steps, you should see it in profile as I describe above.

Comment: @bmike, I see, thanks. Would you mind adding this to the answer?

Comment: Done @mrn you can edit any post here when you have a way to make them better. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/editing